# Pet friendly housing in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, housing, pets

I plan to live in Thailand and am
considering bringing my two indoor cats. I've researched paper work, shipping, etc. but I have not been able to find much information on pet friendly housing. 
What kind of restrictions are common for housing  with pets  in Thailand?

Answer (score 2):

Most places are cat-friendly. Only a few of the more pricey condos don't allow pets. Some will restrict the maximum size of dogs. So you see a lot of little yappy dogs.

The main issue with cats in Thailand is that it is hot here, and my cats (which I brought from Seattle) had a difficult time adjusting to the heat and the bugs. You need to be a lot more careful with the insects here, and you need to make sure your cats have a lot of water available. Also, you can't leave their food out: ants like cat food a lot (and you can find ants everywhere, even on the 30th floor of pretty much any condo - they like to hitch rides on fruit). Plus, the warm humid climate makes food go off quickly.

Comment: Not just food - everything rots so much more quickly here. Headphones, unused electronics, anything with rubber on it. Batteries perish and leak much more quickly here too.